# Problem dynamically sending text message with PHP

Tags: php, sms

I am trying to dynamically send text messages using a PHP script. PHP code:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

$textbody=<<<_MESSAGE_
Some text
_MESSAGE_;

mail('myphonenumber@SMSgateway','subject',$textbody,$headers);
```

I did receive a text message, but it is a "photo message" or rather multimedia instead of text and I am unable to open the message. I have tried playing around with the encoding and *$textbody="this text";* instead of **MESSAGE**.

a) How can I send a normal text message (not multimedia)?

b) Why can't I open it?

c) Is there a way for people to respond to the texts I send with text? When I sent myself a text from hotmail I was able to reply and I got the answer in my inbox. When I tried to put `$header.= 'From: me <me@somedomain.com>' . "\r\n";` the email wouldn't send

> (reason: 553 sorry, your mail was
>   administratively denied. (#5.7.1))

Thanks!

Comment: as each sms gate way is different you should check with them

Comment: that's not my point, the requirements of each in terms of headers etc, are different.

Comment: sorry, as you see I removed my previous comment. I misunderstood the first time I read your answer. Thanks,

Comment: if i was testing it i would start with dropping the extra email headers, then look at some of the other header options.

Comment: Have you tried NOT sending a MIME email? Eliminate the `MIME-Version` and `Content-type` header and it should be treated as text-only.

Comment: Instead of `text/html` try `text/plain` and instead of `From:` try `Reply-To:`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sendTo = "test@test.com";
$subject = trim($_POST['subj']);
$headers = "From: ".$_POST['name']."<" . trim($_POST["email"]) .">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . trim($_POST["email"]) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-path: " . trim($_POST["email"]);
$headers .= "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$message = strip_tags($_POST["messg"]);

if (@mail($sendTo, $subject, $message, $headers))
{ echo "sent successfully"; }
else 
{ echo "Error ... Plz try again later" ; }
```

This code which I'm using to send emails
I worked before on SMS project so if you have any question about how to link with Getaway feel free to contact me